# undefined method on Ruby on Rails 4.2`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined

I have 4 classes, Terminal belongs_to Port, Ports belong to_Country and Countries belong_to Region.

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :countries
end  

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :ports
end

class Port < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :terminals
end

class Terminal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :port
end
```

I'm trying to run following code:

```
class TerminalsController < ApplicationController
    def index    
        @country = Country.find_by name: 'Pakistan'
        @terminals = @country.ports.terminals
    end
end
```

I get following error:
undefined method `terminals` for `#<Port::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fde543e75d0>`

I Get following error:

undefined method `ports` for `<Country::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fde57657b00>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@country.ports` return array of ports, no terminals array is returned. You should declare `has_many :through` relation to `Country` model.

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :ports
  has_many :terminals, through: :ports
end
```

Than at controller,

```
class TerminalsController < ApplicationController
    def index    
        @country = Country.find_by name: 'Pakistan'
        @terminals = @country.terminals # Don't need intermediate ports
    end
end
```

**See also:**

- [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Answer (score 0):

```
@terminals = @country.ports.terminals
```

This line is wrong, ports is ActiveRecord Array.
You would need to do

```
@country.ports.terminals.each do |terminal|
  puts terminal.ports
end
```